# nextcloud: occ maintenance:install leaves web UI in install state

Tags: nextcloud

I am trying to create a dockerfile where nextcloud will be installed through the cli, based on the docker images documented at https://hub.docker.com/_/nextcloud#running-this-image-with-docker-compose.

To test this, I manually run `occ maintenance:install` in the container, with the relevant parameters for admin user and database. After doing this, I see `installed: true` in `occ status`. Also, `occ user:list` shows me the new admin user.

However, after doing this, when I visit the web UI at `http://localhost:8080`, I still see the installation screen with "Create an admin account" and an "Install" button.

Also, requests to the ocs API, e.g. `http://localhost:8080/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users`, don't work.

To move forward and see what happens, I completed the install through the UI, creating a distinct user "admin1".

After doing this, `occ user:list` shows both the "admin" user from the cli installation, and the "admin1" user from the web UI installation. Also the ocs API works now.

So, what might be missing from the cli installation, that the web UI still thinks I need to install and create an admin user?

Answer (score 0):

The confusion is coming from different installation directories.

The docker image contains one "installation" at `/var/www/html` and another at `/usr/src/nextcloud`. The web version uses the former. I suppose the latter is not really meant as an active instance.

For some reason I was using `/usr/src/nextcloud/occ` for `occ`. Obviously I had to use `/var/www/html/occ` instead.

Depending on circumstances, both could use the same database, which would result in users created in web and cli ending up in the same db table.